# Reopen Review Queue seems breaking down

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

Currently I am reviewing on SO, and click Reopen Review queue but got below error message, while all others review queues working fine. I tried 5-6 times, but the same message.

[image]

Comment: seems somebody upload code recently then it breaks

Comment: No repro (edit: ninja'd)

Comment: I just found, that if you press `Refresh` in browser in the moment of loading any queue you see this error but only for 1 sec - it refreshes and error disappears.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My bad. I redacted several revisions there, because they had what appeared to be real credentials in them. Didn't consider review, which went "boom!" trying to render a diff between the current revision and a no-longer-existing previous one.

There is a simple solution to this, so I went ahead and "implemented" it.

Comment: -1 for breaking stuff +1 for fixing it quickly -1 for lack of pictures

Comment: now working fine..

Comment: Continuous Integration? HA! Try 30-minute turnarounds from bug report to live fix.